# Packets do not reach FILTER chain of iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding, arch-linux, arm

I have a problem I cant figure out, I am trying to access webserver on `[RPI]`, but packets never reach `iptables` `FILTER` chain

I will try to explain it a bit:
`GW1` has public address and doing DNAT from port `8080` to `192.168.69.14:80`
`S1` is a openVPN server `eth0` for LAN and `tap0` for VPN are bridged
`[RPI]` has running webserver on port `80`
`GW2` is default gateway for `[RPI]` and has no public address

```
     GW1 <-----------------> S1 <-----Open VPN tunnel------> [RPI] <--Default route--> GW2
(192.168.69.1)        (192.168.69.22)                 (192.168.69.14 - tap0)       (192.168.30.1)
                                                      (192.168.30.2 - wlan0)
```

Now, everything works fine If I reach `[RPI]`'s webserver from `S1`, `GW2` or do a ping from `GW1`
But if I try to access webserver via `GW1`'s public IP on port `8080`, packets do reach `[RPI]`, but disappear in `iptables`., as you can see here, also `iptables` rules are printed below:

```
Apr 27 18:13:51 WeatherStorm kernel: [11383.698445] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:3 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=275 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215BF0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:51 WeatherStorm kernel: [11383.874415] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=275 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215BF0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:51 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.051167] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=275 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215BF0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:51 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.227423] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=275 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215BF0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:52 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.459821] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:3 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=22576 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33137 DPT=80 SEQ=671043022 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215FE0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:52 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.635037] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=22576 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33137 DPT=80 SEQ=671043022 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215FE0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:52 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.811610] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=22576 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33137 DPT=80 SEQ=671043022 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215FE0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:52 WeatherStorm kernel: [11384.988901] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=22576 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33137 DPT=80 SEQ=671043022 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B215FE0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:54 WeatherStorm kernel: [11386.698855] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:3 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B218AD0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:54 WeatherStorm kernel: [11386.874488] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B218AD0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:54 WeatherStorm kernel: [11387.050505] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B218AD0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:13:54 WeatherStorm kernel: [11387.228835] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=82:ed:f9:e6:c2:ea:00:0c:42:f5:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=37.188.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.69.14 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33136 DPT=80 SEQ=3502183596 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405360402080A01B218AD0000000001030307)
```

Raw:

```
[root@WeatherStorm tmp]# iptables -L -nv -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5750 packets, 748K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   27  1620 TRACE      tcp  --  *      *       37.188.XXX.XXX       0.0.0.0/0           
  270 15120 TRACE      icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   51  3958 TRACE      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4768 packets, 911K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        8   448 TRACE      icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
        0     0 TRACE      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            37.188.XXX.XXX
```

Mangle:

```
[root@WeatherStorm tmp]# iptables -L -nv -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4177 packets, 544K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3661 packets, 374K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3498 packets, 674K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3498 packets, 674K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

NAT:

```
[root@WeatherStorm tmp]# iptables -L -nv -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 596 packets, 180K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 80 packets, 9600 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 59 packets, 4443 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 59 packets, 4443 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Filter:

```
[root@WeatherStorm tmp]# iptables -L -nv -t filter
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 23788 packets, 2365K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23777 packets, 5142K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Any idea what/where could be a problem?
If I tried access from `GW2` it looks like

```
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11873.756818] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11873.850894] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11873.945646] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.039622] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.133002] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.226404] TRACE: nat:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38739 DPT=80 SEQ=3482087833 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F44A0000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.319744] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.413794] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.508565] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:02 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.602511] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:04 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.695929] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
Apr 27 18:22:04 WeatherStorm kernel: [11874.789331] TRACE: nat:INPUT:policy:1 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:f3:c1:2f:86:6a:00:1c:bf:8e:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=192.168.30.1 DST=192.168.30.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22857 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=38740 DPT=80 SEQ=3524767168 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A01B3F4890000000001030307)
```

.

### *Solution:*

Solved with following `iptables` rules on `S1`

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.69.14 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat --match mark --mark 1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.69.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routing configuration for `[RPI]` is incorrect — if you want it to be reachable from public Internet addresses via `GW1`, either the default route must point to `GW1`, or (if outgoing connections from `[RPI]` to public Internet addresses must go through `GW2`) you need to configure policy routing on `[RPI]`, so that packets which belong to incoming connections through `GW1` are routed via `GW1`.

(The third option is to make `GW1` also `SNAT` the packets to `192.168.69.1`, so that they will come to `[RPI]` from a directly connected IP, but in this case you will not be able to determine the actual client address on `[RPI]` when handling those packets. For HTTP you can work around this by installing a reverse HTTP proxy on `GW1` instead of using NAT, and passing the real client IP in HTTP headers.)

In your current configuration packets coming from `tap0` which do not come from directly connected hosts may be dropped due to enabled `rp_filter` on that interface (although, according to [ip-sysctl.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt), the default value of `rp_filter` is 0, lots of distributions enable it by default in their networking configuration). If you look at the [netfilter packet flow diagram](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), `rp_filter` is applied at the “routing decision” node, which is consistent with your observations (the last node you see is `nat:PREROUTING`, which is just before the “routing decision” node).

Note that just disabling `rp_filter` will not help you, because reply packets from `[RPI]` will then be just sent via `GW2`, and even if they will somehow reach the other host, it will reject them, because those packets will not have proper NAT processing done on them by `GW1`. You really must make sure that replies to NATed packets which came through `GW1` are sent back to `GW1` — without this NAT will not work properly.

Comment: Would be nice if the kernel made a remark about that for packets being traced...